# How and when should I correctly use the article "the" after a preposition, pron. & det.?

Tags: word-usage

Which sentence is correct looking at the use of the article "the" in bold?

- By a way of illustration, let’s say that **the** Keynesian paradigm identified «full employment» as the core subject of its macroeconomic theory and policy..
- By a way of illustration, let’s say that Keynesian paradigm identified «full employment» as the core subject of its macroeconomic theory and policy..

Comment: Note that [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/by%20way%20of%20illustration) does not list 'by a way of illustration' as a variant of 'by way of illustration'. // How often does "the Keynesian paradigm" occur in reasonable-looking examples on the internet, according to a Google search? How often does the anarthrous (no 'the) string occur, other than in titles (where headlinese tends to kill off articles)?

Comment: In looking this up, I'm coming up with strings like 'The dominant New Keynesian paradigm', 'the anti-Keynesian paradigm' and even '[a] solid post-Keynesian paradigm'. But nearly all non-headlinese examples include an article.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of clarity, include *the* before the subject phrase. *Paradigm* is a singular noun that should be preceded by an article.

In fact, the optional word in your sentence is *that*. It can be removed without impacting the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: Great! Excellent responses